# if ther e is not Hamiltonian cycle in graph G, then G is not planar?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm working on this problem but I am having difficulty convincing myself it is planar. Also, is the implication above correct or is there one similar which talks about planarity and Hamiltonian cycles? We've been taught in class one way to check if graphs are planar is to find Hamiltonian cycle, draw it out as circle with the vertices in order and then try to connect all the missing edges (not used in circle already) without overlapping edges, if you're sucessful it's planar if no then it is not. Problem is I can't find a Hamiltonian cycle...Thanks in advance

[image: here's the problem and what I did so far<code>enter preformatted text here</code>]

Comment: Your graph clearly *is* planar: in the second picture just slide $e$ and $c$ together until they’re inside the quadrilateral $afbd$.

Comment: i wasn't sure that was okay to do. thanks. what about the hamiltonian cycle, it doesn't exist right?

Comment: That’s right, because $fg$ is a bridge. (By the way, you can also simply flip the bridge over, moving it and the triangle $egc$ outside the quadrilateral, so that you have a square and a triangle connected by a bridge.)